# How to update images with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem when I want to update the image.
the update process went well, but the image cannot update.

Please help. Thanks.

Here is View :

```
<?php echo form_open('update'); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $data->id; ?>">
<input type="hidden" id="old" name="old" value="<?php echo $data->image;?>">

<div class="form-group">
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $data->name; ?>">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Change Image</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image">
</div>      
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Here is Controller :

```
public function Update(){ 
$id = $this->input->post('id');
$name = $this->input->post('name');

if($_FILES['image']['name']!=""){
    $config['upload_path']   = './image/';
    $config['allowed_types'] ='gif|jpg|png|jpeg|';
    $this->load->library('upload', $config); 

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('image')){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }else{
        $upload_data=$this->upload->data();
        $image_name =$upload_data['file_name'];
    }
}else{
    $image_name=$this->input->post('old');
}
$data = array( 'name'   => $name, 'image'  => $image_name, );
```

$this->model_user->update_user($data,$id); 
}

Here is Model :

```
public function update_user($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('tabel_user', $data);
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: what means **"image cannot update"?** is there no image in your /image/ directory OR no image_name in your database?

Comment: image cannot be updated in the database. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you code dose not have any mistake. but you use some unwanted input.
try to debug your code.
in model 
before return

```
public function update_user($data, $id)
{
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $this->db->update('tabel_user', $data);
    echo $this->db->last_query();
    echo "</br> id : ".$id;
    print_r($data); EXIT;
}
```

if you get get query printed. check what you have missed. if you don't
at controller
after line `$error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());`
put print_r($error); exit;

and may be you have forgotten to mention multi part at your view.

do these three things hope you will find what is wrong.

Comment: hy, I have added the code that you have provided, but I can't find the wrong code. thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, check your column names are same as array key values 
Try These,

```
public function update_user($data, $id)
{
    echo'<pre>';print_r($data);
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    $flag = $this->db->update('tabel_user', $data);
    echo $flag;die;

}
```

$flag will tell you True or False